# Salir de un bucle cuando encuentra una occurencia en Java

Tags: java

Tengo la siguiente función que busca por toda la lista y cuando encuentra la ocurrencia lo devuelve al final.

```
private static int getIndexRouteInListByRef(List<Route> mArray, String search) {

    int outIndex = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < mArray.size(); i++) {
        if (mArray.get(i).getRef().equals(search)) {
            outIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return outIndex;

}
```

¿Cómo se podría optimizar para que cuando encuentre la ocurrencia salga del bucle y devuelve el indice?

Comment: ¿En java no hay las instrucciones "break" o "continue"?

Comment: supongo, pero toda la vida he sentido que usar break dentro de bucles es una mala práctica

Comment: Supongo que depende del caso... yo prefiero un break bien puesto que mil vueltas para evitarlo.

Comment: Si no te gusta el break puedes incluir la salida en el for, algo como: for (int i = 0; i < mArray.size() && outIndex != i; i++) pero creo que un break se entiende mejor.

Comment: @Webserveis no es una mala práctica usar `break` es lo adecuado. Más bien, tener varios lugares donde hay `return` se puede considerar mala práctica porque el código es un poco más complicado de leer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`break;` Es lo que necesita para salir de cualquier declaración de bucle como `for, while o do-while`.

En su caso, va a ser algo como esto: -

```
private static int getIndexRouteInListByRef(List<Route> mArray, String search) {
        int index = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < mArray.size(); i++) {
            if (mArray.get(i).getRef().equals(search)) {
                index = i;
                break;

            }

        }
        return index;
    }
```

Y si crees que es una mala practica usar el break; te dejo una respuesta de la comunidad en ingles que es muy util y clara, se que debería proporcionar un link con información en español pero puedes usar el traductor de ser necesario. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18188123/is-it-bad-practice-to-use-break-to-exit-a-loop-in-java

Answer (score 5):

En este caso, puedes hacer un `return` dentro del bucle. De hecho, haciéndolo así, ni siquiera necesitas definir una variable `outIndex`:

```
private static int getIndexRouteInListByRef(List<Route> mArray, String search) {

    for (int i = 0; i < mArray.size(); i++) {
        if (mArray.get(i).getRef().equals(search)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Me gusta mucho más tu respuesta. No me gusta el uso de `break` y no necesitas variables adicionales.

Comment: @Error404: Obviamente, yo también prefiero esta opción :) Pero usar `break;` me parece una opción perfectamente válida también en este caso.  De hecho, si el método hubiera incluído más código después del bucle, la opción del `return ...;` ya no se podría usar, de modo que, en ese caso, favorecería el uso de `break;` sin lugar a dudas.

Comment: Yo prefiero siempre utilizar la doble condición en el for antes que el break. Me parece mucho más contextual.

Answer (score 0):

Otra forma de hacerlo sería colocando una condición en el `for`. Este for heredado de C es muy poderoso ya que tiene una condición lógica que funciona como un `while`, de esta forma se puede agregar una condición más para salir del bucle.

```
private static int getIndexRouteInListByRef(List<Route> mArray, String search) {

    //Valor por defecto.
    int nFoundIndex = -1 

    //Se ejecutará MIENTRAS i sea un índice valido del ArrayList
    //Y no se haya encontrado el índice buscado
    for (int i = 0; i < mArray.size() && nFoundIndex == -1; i++) {
        if (mArray.get(i).getRef().equals(search)) {
            nFoundIndex = i;
        }
    }

    return nFoundIndex ;
}
```

De esta forma si llega al final sin encontrar el indice retornará `-1`, pero si lo encuentra, en la siguiente iteración `nFoundIndex` ya no va a valer `-1` y saldrá del bucle.
En mi opinión es la forma más elegante y "pacífica" de salir del bucle antes de tiempo.

Espero que les ayude.